# WSGISocketPrefix not helping with 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I got that 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error when trying to set up mod_wsgi in daemon mode. What make me curious that setting WSGISocketPrefix to /var/run/wsgi or any other directory is not getting me any help. I still have "(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=21696): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process..." in error log.

Can you make me any suggestions? Thank you.

Here is my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/anti1869/blabla/http
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/anti1869/blabla/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/anti1869/blabla/error.log
    <IfModule peruser.c>
        ServerEnvironment anti1869 anti1869
        Processor anti1869 anti1869
    </IfModule>
#   <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
#       SuexecUserGroup anti1869 anti1869
#   </IfModule>
#   <IfModule mod_suexec>
#       SuexecUserGroup anti1869 anti1869
#   </IfModule>
    ServerName blabla.com
    ServerAlias www.blabla.com
    Alias /.awstats/icon /usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/icon

    WSGIDaemonProcess blabla.com user=anti1869 group=anti1869 processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup blabla.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

A mod_wsgi.so compiled for worker or prefork MPM will not work with peruser MPM. Not even sure that if mod_wsgi is compiled from source code whether will work with peruser MPM. What MPM are you using? Is it peruser as suggested by your configuration?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was peruser MPM that was source of the problem. I have recompiled Apache with prefork MPM and it is working fine